# Why does jQuery.inArray not find the value?

Tags: jquery

Does `jQuery.inArray` handle variables? If yes, why this example doesn't work?

**jQuery code:**

```
var arrayOfitems = ["1","2","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","77"];

$(document).ready(function(){

    var searchN = $(#some-element-id).val(); // var searchN = 2;

    if($.inArray(searchN, arrayOfitems) !== -1 )
     {
            alert('is in array');
     }
     else
    {

         alert('is not in array');
    }
});
```

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/vyYE3/2/

Comment: Works if `searchN = "2";` - note the quotes denoting a string.

Comment: Note that if you use `.val()` it should return a string, so that will behave differently to when you hardcode a number with `searchN = 2`: http://jsfiddle.net/vyYE3/4/

Comment: Are you certain `#some-element-id` will have the value you expect right when the `document`  becomes `.ready()`? That event will trigger before the user can alter the value.

Comment: show more real world demo how you are using this...obviously now figured out the numeric issue...but your code should work if element in selector has a value that is in array...WHEN you call this code, and selector is valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array has strings, but you are searching for a number.

Note that `2 == "2"` is `true`, but `2 === "2"` is `false`.

`$.inArray` uses the latter.

Comment: but `val()` returns a string...fiddle may be flawed but code shown should work

Answer (score 1):

It's doing a type check. String 2 is in the array, but Int 2 is not present.

Answer (score 1):

works here with ID of an element http://jsfiddle.net/vyYE3/3/

You need to make this changes though

```
var searchN = $('div').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

If your element is a div, for example:

`<div id="some-element-id">35</div>`

use this:

`var searchN = $('#some-element-id').text();`

Comment: @nnnnnn Don't be a wiseguy. :)